# Find shortest name in string - identify problem in code

Tags: python

I need to find the shortest name in a list of student names.

As far I have typed the following code, but it is not giving me any output.

Can someone help me identify the problem with my code?

```
students = ["a bunch of student names I will not show"]
students.sort(key=len)
shortest_name = (students[0])
print ("The shortest name is ,", shortest_name)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think there is a syntax error here. The last line should be `print("The shortest name is ,", shortest_name)`

Comment: Perhaps you can show your code with made-up student names, so that you can shows us the actual code you're running, the actual output, and explain more clearly what you expect instead. In the state the question is in, you're making us guess a lot of things which doesn't help us or you.

Comment: Regarding `"a bunch of student names I will not show"`, please check how to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

As you have asked shortest name in a `string (not list of strings)`. Working code with minimum changes will be:

```
students = "a bunch of student names I will not show"
students = sorted(students.split(), key=len)
shortest_name = students[0]
print("The shortest name is ,", shortest_name)
```